# PHP script not passing url with a array variable

Tags: php, html

This code is not passing URL to make topic clickable main problem is in third line after while loop. I got this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\xmapp\htdocs\forum\main_forum.php on line 37
```

Code :

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor=#FFFFFF>",$rows['id'],"</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",'<a href="$view_topic.php?id=$rows['id']">$rows['topic'].   </a>',"</td>";


    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",$rows['view'],"</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",$rows['reply'],"</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",$rows['datetime'],"</td>";
}
```

Comment: Please remove the line numbers and format your question properly

Comment: remove your database username and password, we don't need them, just put placeholders there..td align and bgcolor are deprecated, put them in a css file instead....you've put commas instead of periods (full stops ) as concantinators

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor=#FFFFFF>".$rows['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><a href='".$view_topic.".php?id=".$rows['id']."'>".$rows['topic']."</a></td>";


    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$rows['view']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$rows['reply']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$rows['datetime']."</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. there is syntax error in your code.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor=#FFFFFF>",$rows['id'],"</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",'<a href="$view_topic.php?id='.$rows[id].'">'.$rows[topic].  ' </a>',"</td>";


echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",$rows['view'],"</td>";
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",$rows['reply'],"</td>";
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",$rows['datetime'],"</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should correct your problem, Use

`echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><a href='".$view_topic.".php?id=".$rows['id']."'>".$rows['topic']."</a></td>";`

instead of

`echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>",'<a href="$view_topic.php?id=$rows['id']">$rows['topic'].   </a>',"</td>";`

One more thing, Why dont you use php tag only when needed. If you do like this it will be clean and easy.

```
<?php
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><a href ="<?php $view_topic.".php?id=".$rows['id']; ?>"> <?php  $rows['topic']; ?> </a></td>
    .......
   .......
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Working but saying use of undefined constant topic assume of id

Comment: do you have `topic` in your table's column.